# why mongod is shows that attepted to create a lock file on a read-only directory

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2020-05-02T00:18:14.201+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-05-02T00:18:14.201+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Answer (score 0):

`/data/db` is the default data directory path. This can be overridden with the `--dbpath` command-line argument, for example.

If you wish MongoDB to use this default directory to store its files, make it writable by the user that is running the `mongod` process. Otherwise use `--dbpath` to specify a different directory.